# JAVA external Frame to control array

Tags: java

I have very simple code, just 2 buttons to display numbers from array in textArea.

```
public class FotyUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public FotyUI() {
        initComponents();
    }
int[] numbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int position  = 0;

private void nextActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                     
         position ++;
        tekst.setText(" " + numbers[position]);

    }        



private void previousActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
     position--; 
    tekst.setText(" " + numbers[position]);

}
```

Now, this code runs great I have two buttons and textArea, but I would like to create an external JFrame2 with 2 buttons to control/display array from Frame 1
When I type:

```
public class FotyUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {


    public FotyUI() {
        initComponents();
    }
int[] numbers = {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
int position  = 0;



JFrame temp = new JFrame();
JPanel panelik = new JPanel();
JButton nextS = new JButton("Next");
JButton prevS = new JButton("Previous");
panelik.add(nextS);
```

I have an error to create package panelik....
Can u help me ? How to create Frame 2 with 2 buttons and textArea to display/control content of array from Frame1

Answer (score 1):

ok, I solve it !!!!!!!!

```
     JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");
      frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.setSize(500,200);
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      frame.add(panel);
      JButton button = new JButton("hello agin1");
      panel.add(button);
      pole = new JTextField();
      panel.add(pole);
      button.addActionListener (new Action1());
static class Action1 implements ActionListener {        
  public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {     
     position ++;
        tekst.setText(" " + numbers[position]);
  pole.setText(" " + numbers[position]);
  }
}
```